# Regex Search in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, search, phpmyadmin

Attempting to change the "files" folder location in a Drupal site from /files to /sites/default/files.

In order to avoid changing anything else such as

```
  http://www.google.com/profiles/
```

I'm trying to use a basic regular expression with a word boundary.

```
  \bfiles/
```

A quick check in [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) is working as expected, but when I enter the above in the phpMyAdmin search , checking the "as regular expression" checkbox, I don't get the expected result.

Two questions:

- How should I write my expression with a word boundary so that it works in phpMyAdmin?
- I'm really a newbie at SQL statements! Would it be possible to write a SQL query that would simply look for every occurrence of "files/" & replace it with "sites/default/files/"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html), the regex flavour used is POSIX 1003.2. For this flavour of regex, word boundaries are as follows:

`[[:<:]]` (beginning) `[[:>:]]` (end)

so your regex would be:

```
[[:<:]]files/
```

If you want to use sql to search and replace all instances of `[[:<:]]files/` from a specific field in a table, you could [use a UDF such as the one found here](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp)

Also, you should be aware of the following while using regex with MySql:

> Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n”
>   to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you
>   use in your REGEXP strings.

Comment: not really! in your example "files/" will not match, then if I search for "files/" , "profiles/" will also match...

Comment: @PatrickS Ahhh, i see. Sorry, I didn't consider relative paths that don't include the `/`. I've updated my answer with a better solution